# JQuery insertAfter in chrome & safari causes the content to be inserted as String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, dom

i'm using jQuery to insert rows into a table dynamically. the row itself is a (text-) template, which gets some stuff inside replaced, is then 'casted' to an jQuery DOM node. While this works fine in Firefox and IE:

```
jQuery(jQuery.parseHTML(node)).insertAfter("#imgTable tr:last()");
```

Chrome and Safari won't insert the node, but insert the HTML as String. This way i'm not gaining a row, bug a solid block of html sourcecode...which is an UX disaster :)

very simple reproduction:
http://jsfiddle.net/288sp1qb/4/

---

...i already found out that the source of the error is that i store my templates inside a `<noscript>` tag. I have to do that, since all other tags that i know of are interpreted, so most browsers either remove the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags or otherwise modify the content.

storing the template in a variable isn't an option either, since the template already contains some backend generated data. 
so the actual question is: how can i get webkit browsers to interpret the data after inserting them? or: how should i store the templates otherwise?

Comment: What's the actual goal here? Your explanation is unclear and the method you're demonstrating in the fiddle seems unorthodox if anything.

Comment: the content that is parsed into the template is part server side and part client side content, the template itself is part of the delivered html, which makes it easy to access.

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan Please take a look at the answer that I posted in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Code -

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>bsp.</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<noscript id="tpl" style="display:none">
     <tr><td>%VAR%</td></tr>
</noscript>
```

jQuery Code -

```
var node = $("#tpl").text();
node = node.replace("%VAR%","test");
$($.parseHTML(node)).insertAfter("#table tr:last()");
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/s35ppva8/

This solution is working fine in all browsers.

Comment: an "use .text() instead .html()" would have been enough, but thanks nevertheless, this works fine.